# How to receive messages send by NLog with type=Network?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, nlog

I have the following target in my nlog.config :

```
<target name="n1" xsi:type="Network" address="tcp://localhost:4001"/>
```

but have no idea how to receive the massage send by nlog, i am using c#. has anyone implemented it?

Update: my application is a desktop winform and it is on the same machine.

Comment: What do you mean by _"no idea how to receive the message sent by nlog"_? Now, I haven't used NLog specifically, but I would guess the target you specify (it being a network location or a local folder or whatever) is where NLog will _write_ the log messages. You then navigate to that directory (for instance using Windows Explorer, or your favorite file manager) and open the log file in a text editor...

Comment: No, i mean how to get the message via TCP.

Comment: The Chainsaw target is the other alternative, which works with Log2Console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Network" target simply sends your trace message to the configured tcp address. You will need to listen to the given port with a tcp listener to receive it. There are loads of tcp listeners out there, [here](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/TCP-Listener-Download-78987.html) is a very simple one that you can use to verify that your message is received. Typically it will be some kind of management tool that listens for the incoming tcp messages though. You can also write your own listener in C# using the [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) class.